# What's Required for the AudioObject in Schema.org

Tags: sitemap, audio

We're trying to paint our site with the correct Schema.org information, and we're getting the following error:

http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hark.com%2Fclips%2Fskyqpngffn-you-see-what-happens-larry&view=cse

```
 The following errors were found during preview generation:

 Insufficient data to generate the preview.
```

I think the only thing missing would be the actual media URL but we're not able to offer that due to the way our streams are generated. Is there another option?

Answer (score 1):

I get the "Insufficient data to generate the preview." message when looking at my own sites on google's rich snippets tools. After much searching I found that the message is just a generic "error" and doesn't actually relate to the quality of the data. It's most likely that google just doesn't support audio rich snippets yet. I think they only show previews for recipes for the time being. Though I sand to be corrected.

Comment: Boy, wouldn't this be depressing (after they did that big launch of schema.org). I'll up vote your answer, but I'll wait a few days before I accept.

Comment: Well at least you'll be first in line when support is turned on and you'll get an instant boost in your SEO. Similar to you, I just spent two weeks converting my site to HTML5 to use schema only to get the same message. My site is places, tourist attractions and hotels - none of which will create a rich preview.